# Togglebutton not refreshging text after setting it

Tags: android

I am using `ToggleButton` in android and I want to modify `setTextOn` and `setTextOff`.The only problem I engaged is after I change the value I don't get any update from the view untill I don't switch the `toggleButton` state and back again.

I have tryed with `invalidate()` but nothing worked.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a solution, on `ToggleButton` I use the following method to refresh the textOn and textOff: `toggleButton.setChecked(toggleButton.isChecked());`